# get the outer element (LIST) to render anything other than a div

Tags: react-virtualized

Is it possible to get List (or any other component from RV) to render itself like an UL>LI list or specifically like [React Bootstraps ListGroup](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#listgroup).

Currently I can not see an option to get the outer element (LIST) to render anything other than a DIV.

So my use case is really that each row should be a ListGroupItem (e.g. li with BS classes applied) and the container should be a ListGroup component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. This is not supported.

Longer answer: `List` (like `Table`) uses a `Grid` internally. In order for windowing to work, `Grid` needs 2 wrapper elements around its cells. (Check out the source [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/a338c7c1cf8d0ff01128c614dd3596965e69d422/source/Grid/Grid.js#L563-L600). I also made a presentation slide about how it works, if you're interested, [here](https://bvaughn.github.io/connect-tech-2016/#/8/1).) Lists (`ol`, `ul`) only have 1 wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Brian. Turns out, I could just set a couple of BS css classes on the element I returned from rowRenderer and get the styling back again so I really didn't need the UL>LI structure apart from maybe more semantic correct HTML. Great presentation you linked to, I thinks parts of that (or maybe the whole) would be an asset to use as documentation on react-virtualized github page also. Again, thanks!